# Android emulator suddenly stopped to work

Tags: android, xamarin, android-emulator

I am developing an app on Visual Studio with Xamarin. Yesterday emulator was working fine but it stopped to work suddenly without no reason. 
Here is error message from vs console:

```
Starting emulator my_device ...
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -avd my_device -prop monodroid.avdname=my_device
Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-i386.exe: error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'
deleteSnapshot: for default_boot
emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Critical: UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect failed for ptDst=(1113, 122), size=(300x21), dirty=(300x21 0, 0) (Sisteme bağlı bir aygıt çalışmıyor.) ((null):0, (null))
```

Comment: Change the AVD configuration --> Emulated Performance --> Graphics: Software .

Comment: It doesnt work :(

Comment: Please open your Android SDK Manager, check if you have updates, it have it, please update all of them to the latest(especially Android Emulator component), Then create new emulator to make a test.

Answer (score 0):

Go to AVD manager

Try Wipe Data or Cold Boot Now options. [image]

Comment: I tried this but no luck. I tried also uninstall and reinstall emulator. Updating platform tools, system images. None of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times, this error is caused when the system tries to draw something like app borders/edges etc and when it fails, it throws following error of `UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect Failed`

Therefore, it is highly related to graphics, so, try changing your Emulated Graphics in

```
AVD configuration --> Emulated Performance --> Graphics: Software
```

Please note that if you are using Google PlayStore API for Android SDK then  you might not be able change this setting, therefore, if you are unable to change option of Graphics to Software, please create virtual device without PlayStore